# I want to add " " to a very large file holding URL's

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, ide

Using VisualStudioCode, I have a file data that holds 20k URL's. Unfortunatly, they are only seprated with a "," I would like to add " and " to each url. Is there an easy method to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this a few times, and here's my cheaty solution:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to open Find and Replace.
2. Replace all instances of `,` with `","`.
3. Press <kbd>Home</kbd>.
4. Type `"`.
5. Press <kbd>End</kbd>.
6. Type `"`.

Done!

Comment: You would not _believe_ how long this took me to work out; it's one of the pieces of out-of-the-box thinking I'm most proud of. Thanks for giving me an opportunity to share it.